# flink checkpoint stuck on subtask with 0 bytes received

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

One of the subtasks doesn't have any input(i.e. bytes received are 0), and checkpoint of this subtask is stuck.

Is it normal, or is it a bug?

The flink version is 1.6.2.

---

Add more information.
Below is the topology.
[image]

And the third task(i.e. 'Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(30000), ProcessingTimeTrigger, ScalaReduceFunction, PassThroughWindowFunction) -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed') has five subtasks whose 'Bytes received' is 0. And checkpoint stuck on these five subtasks. One of the subtasks is shown as below.
[image]

And every time I restart the application, 'Bytes received 0' happens on different number of subtasks.

Why?

Comment: It will be really hard to help without more info about the pipeline, task and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink 1.6.2 had some bugs related to checkpointing. Can you upgrade to 1.6.4, perhaps, and see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: Thks, I upgrade to 1.11.0, and the problem disappears. Could you provide more info about the bug in 1.6.2, so I can learn more?

Comment: A lot of bugs were fixed in Flink 1.6.3. See the [release notes](https://flink.apache.org/news/2018/12/22/release-1.6.3.html) for details. And of course there have been more bug fixes since then.

Comment: Flink 1.11.3 would be a better choice than 1.11.0. Within each major release (such as 1.11) it is always best to use the latest bug fix release.